# PyMuPDF is deleting whitespaces

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

PyMuPDF is deleting whitespaces and sometimes replacing them with an unknown character "�". When I ask for the text of the page, whitespaces are not deleted, but some are replaced.

The PDF I am working with is this: https://www.sil.org/system/files/reapdata/62/99/18/62991811720566250411942290005522370655/40337_02.pdf

```
doc = fitz.open("40337_02.pdf")
page = doc[3]
print(page.get_text())
```

The code above returns me output like this:

```
abujucùitêmutarabù*�s.m. (clas.
-tarabù) oruga no comestible (de varios
tamaños; de varios colores, algunas
rayadas; lisa; camina como brincando;
algunas personas piensan que si la
dejan caminar en los dedos se les
facilitará tocar guitarra o usar máquina
de escribir). Fam. Geometridae.
pl.�abujucùitêmutarabùa. V.�ãcùriocù.
abujucùñùabo�s.inan. (clas. -bo) nido
de los comejenes abujucùñùabo
(pequeño; duro; encima del suelo en
cualquier parte; hecho de tierra
mezclada con su saliva; los cubeos
golpean las rodillas de los niñitos con
este nido para que aprendan a caminar
más pronto). pl.�abujucùñùaboa.
V.�bocomibo.
—s.m. (clas. -bo, clas. -rù) comején
(muy pequeño; blanco; come madera
podrida y tierra; forma alternativa:
abujucùñùarù). Isoptera.
pl.�abujucùñùaboa, abujucùñùarùa.
V.�bocomicù.
```

Now, when I try code like this:

```
blocks = page.get_text("dict", flags=11)["blocks"]
for block in blocks: 
     for line in block["lines"]: 
         for span in line["spans"]:
             print(span["text"])
```

I get undesired results like this:

```
abujuõrecaje
�
s.inan.
(clas.-caje)cáscara
de
abujuõreve
(negra).
pl.
�
abujuõrecajea.
```

Notice how the whitespace after the closing parenthesis is deleted. This is an isolate example, but that happens all over the document. I need to iterate through spans, but I need whitespaces to stay. What have I overlooked?

Comment: Text extraction in PyMuPDF is a very powerful method that can also extract images, detect hyphenation, font, font size, writing direction, text coordinates, text color, disassemble ligatures, respect white space or convert to normal space, generate missing spaces, output HTML, XHTML, XML strings, JSON, dictionaries, single words or down to single characters, etc. -- To ensure compatible results across different extraction variants you must therefore use the same flags parameter. In you case, you should therefore use `get_text("dict", flags=fitz.TEXTFLAGS_TEXT)` for compatible results.